# DataBinding Collection and change element of collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, windows-8.1

I have a colection and a ListView to which I have binded a collection of objects:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Levels}"... />
```

Here is a Levels collection:

```
private ObservableCollection<Level> _levels;
public ObservableCollection<Level> Levels
{
    get { return _levels; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _levels, value); }
}
```

And here is a Level class:

```
public class Level : BindableBase
{
    private double _value;
    public double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _value, value); }
    }

    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get {  return _isChecked; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _isChecked, value); }
    }

    public SolidColorBrush ForegroundColor
    {
        get { return IsChecked ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.BlueViolet); }
    }
}
```

If I add element in the collection, the new element will be displayed in the ListView, but if I change the existing element of collection I can not see any change:

```
private void LvLevels_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (LvLevels.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        selectedLevel = (Level)LvLevels.SelectedItem;                                      
        foreach (var l in viewModel.Levels)
        {                   
           if (l.Value == selectedLevel.Value)                    
              l.IsChecked = true;  // it doesn't work                                                          
           else
              l.IsChecked = false; 
        }   

        // it works
        // viewModel.Levels.Add(new Level { Value = 10, IsChecked = true});                             
    }
```

Why and how can I fix it ?

**Update**

Here is my ItemTemplate:

```
                      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Image Grid.Column="0" 
                                   Source="../Assets/icons/зоны.png"
                                   Margin="10 0 0 0"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="tblock" Text="{Binding Value}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="30"
                                          Foreground="{Binding ForegroundColor}" />
                                <!--  Style="{StaticResource ZoneButtonText}" -->
                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expect the `ForegroundColor` to change (that's a guess), you need to make sure the WPF components *know* it has changed. You need to send a change notification for `ForegroundColor` when `IsChecked` changes, too.

Oh, and don't compare doubles using `==`. Doubles are [floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) variables.

Comment: Yes, I bind ForegroundColor to the TextBox in the ItemTemplate.  And it looks like you are right. If I change `l.Value` then the changes makes visible.  Can you please explain how can I `send a change notification for ForegroundColor when IsChecked changes, too` ? Thanks.

Comment: You can call `OnPropertyChanged("ForegroundColor");` after your call to `SetProperty` in your IsChecked setter.